# How to call other method if UIBarButtonItem action is fired in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

i am creating an iPhone application. Currently i am displaying UIBarButtonItem of my **"first"** class with target of **"second"** class, so i am giving my UIBarButtonItem action method to the second class. And it's working fine.

**here is my code for my First class with target of second class i.e. "revealController":**

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightRevealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MENU"
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];
```

**here is my UIBarButtonItem method of Second class:**

```
- (void)rightRevealToggle:(id)sender
{    
    [self rightRevealToggleAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now, my problem is that i am displaying Slide Show images in my First class, so i need to stop slide show, when user will tap on "rightRevealToggle" i.e. UIBarButtonItem action method. If there target will be same then it's easy to set slide show stop action along with UIBarButtonItem action method. But in my case, i am using Slide Show in my First Class and it's not declared to the Second class.

here is my slide show stop method, that i need to call when user will tap on UIBarButtonItem action method

```
[slideshow stop];
```

Please suggest me some way that i can achieve my output. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with barbuttonitem initialization assign a property of revealController (named FirstController for example.)

**RevealController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) FirstController *firstController;
```

**FirstController.m**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad () {

....

[revealController setFirstController: self];
....
UIBarButtonItem *rightRevealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MENU"
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];

....
}
```

**RevealController.m**

```
- (void)rightRevealToggle:(id)sender
{    
    [self rightRevealToggleAnimated:YES];

    // call instance method of FirstController

   [firstController stopSlideShow]; // this will navigate your pointer to FirstController class where you can access slide show method and properties
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry but I can see you have accepted my answer, but not upvoted. Hit the up arrow button above 0.

Answer (score 0):

In short you have to get the instance of you first Class inside your method rightRevealToggle and then call [instanceOfFirstClass stop];

say instance of FirstClass(eg:insFirstClass) has been loaded into memory that is playing slide show. I assume it has a stop method declared in FirstClass.h

so in the SecondClass when rightRevealToggle is called, I assume your FirstClass instance insFirstClass is still in memory and running slide show method.

Now you have to get the access to the insFirstClass instance of FirstClass that is already running slide show in the memory(say for eg: you have pushed this instance in navigationController).

After the insFirstClass is in your hold in SecondClass within the method

```
-(void)rightRevealToggle:(id)sender
{
 //your extra logic
 //...
 //...
  FirstClass *insFirstClassInSecondClass = [from navigationcontroller.viewcontrollers or any other blah blah stuff];
  [insFirstClassInSecondClass stop];

 //your extra logic
 //...
 //...
}
```

Note: I hope you are getting an idea and understanding my answer. If no ,please let me know so that I'll edit answer to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved using  `NSNotificationCenter`

In your `viewController1` (where i suppose you are starting slider) when you start slider you can add an observer and add selector `stopSlider`

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopSlider) name:@"stopSliderNotification" object:nil];
```

and add a selector named stopSlider

```
-(void)stopSlider{
    // Code For Stopping Slider here
}
```

Now from any Other ViewController when you want to stop slider you can post stopSliderNotification and it will call `stopSlider` selector of `viewController1` using following code

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"stopSliderNotification" object:nil];
```

This will work nicely for this scenario , hope this helps.